How to stop RunDeck job to run on other nodes if one node is successful
I am new to RunDeck and I got a task to create a Job, which runs on 4 nodes.
The ask is to run this job on one node and if that is successful then stop the execution. If the job is failed then go to next node.
And finally if all nodes are failed then mark the JOB as failure else Success.
I have used an option to stop execution if a step is FAILED but I do not find any option to stop execution if a step is SUCCESS.
Could you please help me here?

The Ruleset Strategy (Process Automation's exclusive feature) is designed for that kind of scenario, take a look at this.
Now, on Rundeck OSS you need to make some script-fu. I made an example that needs two jobs: the job that you need to dispatch, let's call it "MyJob", and the "executor" job, this job executes the first one with a specific logic, and decides if to keep trying on the next nodes or not.
MyJob: this is just a simple job with a filter.
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 9fcc183b-b4df-4554-b75b-c660eda706b3
  loglevel: INFO
  name: MyJob
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  nodefilters:
    dispatch:
      excludePrecedence: true
      keepgoing: false
      rankOrder: ascending
      successOnEmptyNodeFilter: false
      threadcount: '1'
    filter: ${option.thenode}
  nodesSelectedByDefault: true
  options:
  - name: thenode
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: {}
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - exec: cat file
    keepgoing: true
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 9fcc183b-b4df-4554-b75b-c660eda706b3

The Executor Job: Executes the first job with a specific behavior: after finding a successful execution in one particular node, stop executing on the rest of the nodes.
- defaultTab: nodes
  description: ''
  executionEnabled: true
  id: 18bbd45e-5301-4498-8b92-0c4828194b61
  loglevel: INFO
  name: Executor
  nodeFilterEditable: false
  plugins:
    ExecutionLifecycle: {}
  scheduleEnabled: true
  sequence:
    commands:
    - fileExtension: sh
      interpreterArgsQuoted: false
      script: |-
        #!/bin/bash

            # script that detects only when all nodes fail
            # based on the following answer:
            # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58798856/rundeck-fail-a-job-only-when-all-nodes-fail

            #####################################################
            # rundeck instance values
            server="localhost"
            port="4440"
            api="46"
            jobid="9fcc183b-b4df-4554-b75b-c660eda706b3"
            token="gYo7evX3rh1YKu1nfNSSgzy0xOMKr2jp"

            #####################################################
            # 1 - succeeded at least in one node
            # 0 - failed, keep trying
            #####################################################
            flag=0

            #####################################################
            # here put all nodes to pass via options, like a list
            mynodes=node00,node01,node02

            #####################################################
            # "prudential" time between actions
            pt="2"

            for currentnode in $(echo $mynodes | sed "s/,/ /g"); do
                if [ "$flag" -gt 0 ]; then
                    echo "the job has been succeeded in $currentnode"
                    exit 0
                else
                    sleep $pt
                    execid=$(curl -s -H accept:application/json --data-urlencode "argString=-thenode $currentnode" http://$server:$port/api/$api/job/$jobid/run?authtoken=$token | jq -r '.id')

                    sleep  $pt
                    status=$(curl -s --location --request GET "http://$server:$port/api/$api/execution/$execid/state?authtoken=$token" | jq -r '.executionState')

                    # if job runs OK, then assign the value 1 to flag
                    if [ "$status" = "SUCCEEDED" ]; then
                        flag=1
                    fi
                fi
            done
      scriptInterpreter: /bin/bash
    keepgoing: false
    strategy: node-first
  uuid: 18bbd45e-5301-4498-8b92-0c4828194b61

Here is the script if you need to take a look "out of the job"
#!/bin/bash

    # script that detects only when all nodes fail
    # based on the following answer:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58798856/rundeck-fail-a-job-only-when-all-nodes-fail

    #####################################################
    # rundeck instance values
    server="localhost"
    port="4440"
    api="46"
    jobid="9fcc183b-b4df-4554-b75b-c660eda706b3"
    token="gYo7evX3rh1YKu1nfNSSgzy0xOMKr2jp"

    #####################################################
    # 1 - succeeded at least in one node
    # 0 - failed, keep trying
    #####################################################
    flag=0

    #####################################################
    # here put all nodes to pass via options, like a list
    mynodes=node00,node01,node02

    #####################################################
    # "prudential" time between actions
    pt="2"

    for currentnode in $(echo $mynodes | sed "s/,/ /g"); do
        if [ "$flag" -gt 0 ]; then
            echo "the job has been succeeded in $currentnode"
            exit 0
        else
            sleep $pt
            execid=$(curl -s -H accept:application/json --data-urlencode "argString=-thenode $currentnode" http://$server:$port/api/$api/job/$jobid/run?authtoken=$token | jq -r '.id')

            sleep  $pt
            status=$(curl -s --location --request GET "http://$server:$port/api/$api/execution/$execid/state?authtoken=$token" | jq -r '.executionState')

            # if job runs OK, then assign the value 1 to flag
            if [ "$status" = "SUCCEEDED" ]; then
                flag=1
            fi
        fi
    done

The logic is to delegate the behavior in the script step.
